# Need to delete a row if it is occurring twice in a year and quarter with different status

Tags: sql, sql-server

consider a EMP table

```
EID   ENAME    YEAR   QUARTER   AMOUNT    STATUS
101    ABC     2001     1        1000     PAID
101    ABC     2001     1        1000     UNPAID
102    DEF     2001     1        2000     PAID
103    xyz     2001     1        3000     PAID
103    xyz     2001     1        3000     UNPAID
```

Need to delete a row  if and only if the eid is repeated twice,with two different statuses,
need to delete only rows of "paid" status.

Output:

```
EID   ENAME    YEAR   QUARTER   AMOUNT    STATUS
101    ABC     2001     1        1000     UNPAID
102    DEF     2001     1        2000     PAID
103    xyz     2001     1        3000     UNPAID
```

Trying this way but it is not working:

```
With ctE_d(EID,ENAME,REPORTYEAR, REPORTQUARTER,SALARY,STATUS,rownumber)
as (
select EID,ENAME,REPORTYEAR, REPORTQUARTER,SALARY,STATUS, row_number()over(partition by EID,ENAME,REPORTYEAR, REPORTQUARTER,SALARY,STATUS 
order by EID,ENAME,REPORTYEAR, REPORTQUARTER,SALARY,STATUS)as rank from EMPSAMPLE
WHERE STATUS='PAID')
delete from cte_d where rownumber<>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t
create table #t(EID varchar(5),ENAME varchar(10),[YEAR] int,[QUARTER] int,AMOUNT int, [STATUS] varchar(10))
insert into #t
select '101','ABC',2001,1,1000,'PAID' union all
select '101','ABC',2001,1,1000,'UNPAID' union all
select '102','DEF',2001,1,2000,'PAID' union all
select '103','xyz',2001,1,3000,'PAID' union all
select '103','xyz',2001,1,3000,'UNPAID'

delete t from (
   select *,row_number()over(partition by eid order by STATUS desc) as rn from #t
) as t where t.rn>1 and t.status='PAID'

select * from #t
```

```
    EID ENAME   YEAR    QUARTER AMOUNT  STATUS
1   101 ABC 2001    1   1000    UNPAID
2   102 DEF 2001    1   2000    PAID
3   103 xyz 2001    1   3000    UNPAID
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a CTE and window functions.  Assuming the status only takes on two values:

```
with todelete as (
      select e.*,
             min(status) over (partition by eid) as mins,
             max(status) over (partition by eid) as maxs
      from emp e
     )
delete from todelete
    where mins <> maxs and status = 'PAID';
```

Comment: I'm betting because they attempted to use row_number in their OP, and that's what Nolan used so it made more sense to them, personally. Just a guess.